# How to access my a1.mp3 file after install app using play asset delivery? Another question is: May I see the file into the device? Thanks in advance

Tags: android, google-play

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip5Zr.png)I am using Android Studio. I could not understand android tutorial. Please, show me some example of how to play my mp3 file after download files from asset folder to device, using media player. Is there a way to see if the download was done in fact? I understood that the download is automatic, without code, is it right? My asset is fast-follow. Play store shows download being done, but I did not find a1.mp3 into device.

I want to publish a new app in play store. My final app will have almost 2Gb. It is the first time that I use Play Asset Delivery.